How would my frogs mutually benefit from fireflies?
I have big marsh frogs with a mutually symbiotic relationship with fireflies. They swallow up the fireflies and keep them inside their bodies without killing them. Their stomach have specialized sections meant to house the fireflies. Whenever the frog croaks and its throat expands, the light of the fireflies can be vaguely seen glowing within it, resembling a lamp. When the population of fireflies grows big enough, the frog 'vomits' them out, creating a cycle for the next frog to perpetuate.
For the fireflies, entering the frogs is good for them because it offers them protection from predators, a convenient shelter, and an easy food source whenever the frogs eat something.
The frogs aren't apex predators so the glowing light makes them very visible to potential predators.
How would the frogs mutually benefit from this, enough to justify the issue of visibility?

The frogs may not be apex predators... but they are predators
Image courtesy Plunkett's Pest Control, which is kinda on-topic when you think about it.
There are a variety of reasons for, generally, bioluminescence in nature. They include:

Defense
There are many ways animals can use bioluminescence as a defensive mechanism. One of the simplest ways is to shock or scare a predator away through sudden bursts of light, a behavior typical to many shrimp species.
Attack
There are two ways predators can use bioluminescence as a form of attack: mimicry and illumination.
Communication
Fireflies attract a mate using bioluminescence. Depending on the species, there are two ways this can happen. In some species, the female emits light, which attracts the male, while in others, the male emits light signals to communicate with the females. (Source)

While any of these could be part of the lore of your frogs, I'm voting for attack. The light lures prey (say, moths) to the frog. The fireflies may be shunted to a nice holding cell... but the other insects go straight to the gastric acid.
Image courtesy ibid.
The frogs don't need so much light that it attracts their predators, only enough to draw local insects to them.
Parasitic symbiotic bioluminescence... cool.

A Mating Display
The frog with the brightest glow has obviously managed to catch the most insects, and is thus the best prospective mate. That's how it started.
However, this display greatly favored frogs that kept their caught fireflies alive, since a dead firefly's glow would fade.
Over time, the two species have co-evolved into the current relationship.

I think this is the best answer, simply because this is the reason the frog croaks and expands its throat in the first place. Why complicate it?

this is  the best answer since Sexual Selection Pressure is most likely to produce quick, and "weird" adaptations like that. Pretty much every time we observe some very bizarre creature in nature, one with flashy, silly or over-the-top adaptation, its for sex.

One possible workaround to the problem: the fireflies do not have to reside somewhere in the stomach. They can enter the frog's vocal sac. This way, they will provide a better light show, since the sac is closer to the skin and is translucent when it inflates. The light may attract some predatory insects, of which many are the firefly's predators. In addition to protection, the vocal sac will provide a bubble of air to breathe when the frog is swimming underwater. The fireflies in your story are in their larval form. They migrate to the stomach to feed on whatever the frog catches (though it leaves most of the food to sustain the frog, they eat their share) and return to the vocal sac. Just as parasites have evolved to live inside the digestive tract without being digested, they have evolved the same way. The adult fireflies find their way out. After mating, the female finds the next frog in which she will lay her eggs.

It's a form of predator aversion (like reverse advertising).
Such a glow at night will deter any predator that seeks it out - a croak coupled with a glow are burned into the predator's evolution just the same way as a Swallowtail Caterpillar does:

AI generated image, no accreditation for copyright needed.
The bright colours are a deterrent to birds that would normally
dine on anything wriggly. This is referred to as apostematism, a type of crypsis.
In the case of your frogs, the glow-bugs might be decidedly deadly to birds or other predators - the frog ancestors who'd been infested by glow flies
would have been poisonous to the predator - those predators would be wiped out, those frogs would survive and breed - leaving only those predators who had a slight aversion to the croak coupled with a glow.
Over evolutionary time the effect would multiply and compass the entire local species.
Then, there's the phenomenon of apostematism mimicry - a creature (or plant) that exhibits this will be like another creature that's poisonous. This would work like other similar situations - perhaps a glow from a hollow branch in a tree might have deterred the birds from investigating glows - or another creature that swallows glow flies - or another species of glow fly that has a sting or is poisonous.

This is even more appropriate since the bioluminsensce of fireflies is itself, at least partially, an example of apostematism.
